# add and remove classes that toggle open and close full screen navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a full screen navigation menu that opens when I click the hamburger icon. Right now I am able to toggle the navigation by adding a class called "open" that triggers when I click on the menu. But I am stuck when it comes to closing it. Could you review my code and let me know what I'm missing?

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').on('click', function() {
       $('.overlay').addClass('open');
       $('#menu').removeClass('open-menu');
       $('#menu').addClass('close-menu');
    });
   
    $('.#menu').on('click', function() {
      $('.overlay').removeClass('open');
      $('#menu').addClass('open-menu');
      $('#menu').removeClass('close-menu');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

use toogle function for this like

```
$( "#target" ).toggle(function() {
  alert( "First handler for .toggle() called." );
}, function() {
  alert( "Second handler for .toggle() called." );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I simplified it a bit and so far it works great!